# Mobile Safari opens a new window when window.location.hash changes on web app

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, window.location

I have a single page web app that changes it state by changing the window.location.hash and I have an event listener to process the hash and display things according hash value, like this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    processWindowHash();
});
```

The users can add the web app to their home screen and use it, but at their first action it opens a new window because of the window.location.hash change.

I have the following meta on my page's head:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

I tried to follow every hash change (like `window.location.hash = 'foo';`) with a `return false` statement, without success.

Is there any solution to this problem or I have to use another way to change the app state instead of window.location.href?

I found other questions similar to this, but all other questions were about catching page link clicks (like `<a href="">foo</a>`). I found nothing about `window.location.hash` changes.